# Pandas na_rep() equivaent in openpyxl save() parameter

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

is there a parameter or a function in `openpyxl` that has an equivalent to `na_rep()` of Pandas?

The reason I needed to use `save()` of openpyxl is because I created a function that will make a merged header(using `openpyxl`) with conditional format that I will append to another excel file, say **wb1.xlsx**.

**wb1.xlsx** contains specific columns that I added string values using `.fillna()` of Pandas. Although my objective is to fill other blank cells with another `string`.

Or is the only way is to use `iterrows()` and fill the blanks?

Comment: What does `na_rep()` do? In openpyxl you don't need to explicitly create blank cells, all cells without values are implicitly blank.

Comment: na_rep() can place `string` value to blank or empty cells in a dataframe. What I need to do is to fill those blank cells `string` values

Comment: Provide an example of what you have and what you need it to be.